# How to Control the toggle with anchor tag with href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a Collapse and Expand functionality using Jquery in my left menu.

Here when user clicks "Parent", would like to show "Admin" and "Account" with anchor tag with url. It is working fine till this point.

If user clicks on "Admin", it is collapsing and showing root element "Parent".

How to hold the structure here.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.child').hide();

    $('li:has(.child)').click(function() {
        $('ul',this).toggle('slow');
    });

    $('li').click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a>Parent</a>
            <ul class-"child">
                <li class="child"><a href="/Home/Admin">Admin</a></li>
                <li class="child"><a href="/Home/Account">Account</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Without an anchor tag it will work fine but when I include anchor tag with url, "stopPropagation" event over li will fail. That makes it to collapse to the root element.

If User clicks on Admin it will collapse to the root as

```
.Parent
```

what to do to hold the structure as below

```
.Parent
  .Admin
  .Account
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am getting, you click on the "Admin" or "Account", it will redirect to the appropriate page and at the time you want to open up the hierarchy in which it lies.

In this case what you can do is, compare the current url with each a tag in the hierarchy and compare the url. `window.location.pathname` can be used to get the path you want to compare and [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to loop through the a tags. Let me know if you have still doubt in it.

Comment: Yes, I want to display the left hierarchy in which it lies. Code reference would be a great help

Comment: `var currentURL = window.location.pathname;

$('#nav .child li').each(function(){
 var aHref = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
  if( aHref == currentURL )
  {
   $(this).closest('ul.child').show();
  }
});`

Let me know if you do not get anything.

Comment: If its helpful to you, up vote would be really helpfull :)

Comment: The code will it self only show the parent on load unless child has not been visited. For your current example, it admin is currently visited, it will show the children too as it inner. Else only the parent will be showed up.

Comment: It is holding the left section and redirecting respective page in right section. but I am not seeing toggle effect here. correct me if I am wrong

Comment: May I have the URL if its live?

Comment: Yes. But it must collapse on "Parent" click

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
$('div.toggle').hide();
$('ul.product-info li a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('div').slideToggle(200);
});
```

Here is the page about that in the jQuery documentation:

http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/#preventdefault

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.child').hide();

    $('.parent').click(function() {
        $('ul.child',this.parent).toggle('slow');
    });

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="parent">Parent</a>
            <ul class="child">
                <li><a href="#/Home/Admin">Admin</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/Home/Account">Account</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This should work. 
Your problem is that when you click on li you clicked on parent li before.

Comment: It is navigating but left menu collapse to the base. When I click on Admin, left menu shows only Parent and right will display Home/Admin page.
I want to hold the left section - Parent - Admin

Comment: It's because your browser is redirecting put `#/Home/Admin` in your url

Comment: It is not working as required. After click on "Admin", Right section is navigating but left section shows only "Parent".

Comment: I have updated the snippet, some mistakes from me, sorry. Can you re try with this ?

Comment: Right section is not loading with the respective page . If user clicks on "Admin" then I would like to load right section with "/Home/Admin".

Comment: just change the HREF

Comment: By changing the href as suggested by you, url is looks like "localhost:52274/#/Admin/BarcodeForm" because of this it is not navigating.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Below is the working code for it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.child').hide();

    $('li:has(.child)').click(function() {
        $('ul',this).toggle('slow');
    });

    $('li').click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
  
  });
```

```css
a{
  color: blue;
    text-decoration: none;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a>Parent</a>
            <ul class="child">
                <li class="child"><a href="/Home/Admin">Admin</a></li>
                <li class="child"><a href="/Home/Account">Account</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

***Hoping this will help you :)***

Comment: Left menu is not holding its structure. It is collapsing to the base.

Comment: you want to keep it open.. i mean parents and child by default?

Comment: When page opens I want to show only root element that is "Parent". On click of "Parent" would like to display "Admin" and "Account" . Now if user click on "Admin" then Left menu must hold the structure as is and right section must navigate.

Comment: right section means? you want us to add new container and display content of admin and account in that. meanwhile the parent child will reman as it.. correct?

Comment: I have two section in a page - Left is menu and right section will display the selected page from the left section. When user click on Child element - "Admin", right section is showing respective page but left section is toggling to root element and showing only "Parent"

Comment: ohk got now.. let me check